# Spark sql streaming with Kafka on Json data : Function from_json not able to parse multiline json coming from kafka topic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

Here, I am Sending the json data to kafka from "test" topic ,give the schema to json, do some transformation and print it on console.
Here is the code:-

```
val kafkadata = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("max.poll.records", 10)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
    .load()



val schema1 = new StructType()
    .add("id_sales_order", StringType)                               
    .add("item_collection",                                         
    MapType(                                             
      StringType,
      new StructType()
        .add("id", LongType)
        .add("ip", StringType)
        .add("description", StringType)
        .add("temp", LongType)
        .add("c02_level", LongType)
        .add("geo",
          new StructType()
            .add("lat", DoubleType)
            .add("long", DoubleType)
        )
    )
  )



val df = kafkadata.selectExpr("cast (value as string) as 
           json")
           .select(from_json($"json",
schema=schema1).as("data"))
.select($"data.id_sales_order",explode($"data.item_collection"))




 val query = df.writeStream
    .outputMode("append")
    .queryName("table")
    .format("console")
    .start()
  query.awaitTermination()
  spark.stop()
```

I am sending data to kafka by 2 ways:-

1) Single line json:-

```
 {"id_sales_order": "2", "item_collection": {"2": {"id": 10,"ip": "68.28.91.22","description": "Sensor attached to the container ceilings","temp":35,"c02_level": 1475,"geo": { "lat":38.00, "long":97.00}}}}

It is giving me output
+--------------+---+--------------------+
|id_sales_order|key|               value|
+--------------+---+--------------------+
|             2|  2|[10,68.28.91.22,S...|
+--------------+---+--------------------+
```

2)Multiline json:-

```
{
  "id_sales_order": "2",
  "item_collection": {
    "2": {
      "id": 10,
      "ip": "68.28.91.22",
      "description": "Sensor attached to the container ceilings",
      "temp":35,
      "c02_level": 1475,
      "geo":
        { "lat":38.00, "long":97.00}
    }
}
}

It is not giving me any output.
+--------------+---+-----+
|id_sales_order|key|value|
+--------------+---+-----+
+--------------+---+-----+
```

Json coming from source is like 2nd one.

How do you handle json while reading streaming data from kafka?
I think the problem may be that the from_json function doesn't understand multiline json.

Comment: What version of spark are you using?

Comment: can you try make to single line like this `.selectExpr("REPLACE(CAST(value as string), '\n', '') as json")` ?

Comment: I am using 2.2.2 version.